# How to implement the stack monitoring provided by Kibana in Datadog?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, datadog

I would like to implement the Stack Monitoring provided by Kibana in Datadog.

[[Imgae] kibana stack monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36RMx.png)

First, I tried the following to implement Search Rate, but it looks different from what Kibana provides.

```
per_minute(avg:elasticsearch.search.query.total{$kube_namespace, $elastic_cluster})
```

[[Imgae] Search Rate implementation I tried in Datadog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOKdR.png)

The description of Search Rate in Kibana looks like below, is it possible to implement it in Datadog?

```
Number of search requests being executed across primary and replica shards. A single search can run against multiple shards!
```

and, can we also implement search latency, indexing rate, and indexing latency?

Any help would be much appreciated ‍♂️